# Using Qt Undo Framework With QPainter

Tags: c++, qt

I am creating a drawing application with Qt and want to include undo and redo commands for whatever is drawn on a QImage. For this, I want to at least try and incorporate the Qt undo framework, since manually doing it will probably be above my skill level. 
I have a MainWindow class where the main work is done and where I have the menu with undo and redo QActions. 
The painting is done in a QWidget class called DrawingArea like this (PenShape is an enum of shapes):

```
void DrawingArea::drawLine(const QPoint &endPoint) {
QPainter painter(&image);

//some pen config code

switch (currentShape){
case PenShape::Polygon:
    painter.drawPolygon(&endPoint, 5, Qt::OddEvenFill);
    break;
case PenShape::Line:
    painter.drawLine(lastPoint, endPoint);
    break;
//other shapes and their draw methods..
}
update()
}
```

So as can be seen, the painter can draw in multiple shapes. I know I would have to somehow transfer this to a QUndoCommand class, but how? The drawline method is called only in DrawingArea's mouse event methods like this:

```
void DrawingArea::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event){
if (event->button() == Qt::LeftButton) {
        lastPoint = event->pos();
    }
}
```

The QtUndoStack is located in MainWindow and the QActions are also there, but somehow I would have to connect the drawLine QtUndoCommand class and the mousePressEvent and mainWindow QAction with its connected slot method all together. This is what I don't know how to do.

Any help is appreciated!

Edit, here's the menu button actions:

```
m_undo = undoStack->createUndoAction(this, tr("&Undo"));
m_undo->setShortcuts(QKeySequence::Undo);

m_redo = undoStack->createRedoAction(this, tr("&Redo"));
m_redo->setShortcuts(QKeySequence::Redo);
```

I have no QUndoCommand classes because I'm unsure of how to create them yet. 
In my MainWindow, I have a undoStack declared like this:

```
undoStack = new QUndoStack(this);
```

Comment: Gave my best try at it, have a look. I thought I removed enough code the last time for it to be understandable.

Comment: I do not understand, have you read that it is an MCVE ?, your code is not. When they ask you for an MCVE the main thing is complete and verifiable, the minimum is secondary since it is the easiest to obtain.

Comment: How about you just ask me what is confusing? I thought this was complete enough, as the mentioned code is what needs to be changed.. I added all else that I have in the code related to the undo/redo actions at the moment.

Comment: No, if you want to use undo-redo the first thing is to identify what the commands are. In your code I can not identify what a command is since it is not understood what kind of actions exist. Are the commands differentiated by the shape? If your question was clear, I would not ask for an MCVE. Please read the link so that you understand that I am asking you. If you do, you tell me, it's annoying that I have to invest comments to convince him of something I've clearly asked from the beginning.

Comment: her* and it was not clearly asked. I would have added them if I had any. Since I don't know how to use the QUndoCommand classes in this case (it is unlike the examples on the Internet), I have nothing to add. My apologies. I am a beginner with Qt and C++.

Comment: I have the same problem in PyQt; My best guess would be to extend QUndoCommand and have said command store both the action (pen & path) and the drawn-over component of the image, with the redo function painting that image over the current to redo. Alternatively, you could look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64874382/pyqt5-undo-implementation [python but similar idea] and instead of redoing, store the commands and a set starting point and just performing all the commands in sequence up to the point in history you want. Two years two late, I know, but hopefully this helps someone